# Bootstrap Juju to Maas controller

Tags: 16.04, juju, maas

I have a working Maas setup with one controller. Now I have installed Juju on this controller. The question is: Can I bootstrap the maas-cloud also to the controller  with the Maas & Juju installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is that you cannot.  I have tried to put the juju GUI on the MaaS juju system with no success, and was told that the juju server could not deploy to itself.
What you could do is set up a VM on that server and add it to MaaS, them deploy to it.
[Edit]
On second thought, I think I made your question.  I believe that did bootstrap to the local machine.  This was 2 years ago, so until 14.04, and I'm not sure what version of juju.  I'm building a VM with 16.04 and will let you know my results.